# submit a google Form, create PDF from google sheets and send Email with attached PDF, and Email has a HTML template for the body of the email

Tags: javascript, forms

[screenshot is of the PDF been sent as you can see the " {de}" is not change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crboS.png)

[Screenshot of google sheet with answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkSzu.png)

[Screenshot Of Email been sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g148r.png)

this is my 3rd scrip using App Scrip, and I'm have one last problem, What I'm doing is a entry is made using google Forms, I need to create a PDF from the entry in google sheets, PDF is attached and is sent.

I'm able to create everything, but the PDF is not updated with the results.
I will include the code below and the HTML template.

```
`function createPDF(){
  const id = 'file ID 123456789';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PDF-Data');
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().slice(1);
  const emailTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('qaemail.html');
  const pdfTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pdfTemplate.html');

  data.forEach((row,ind)=>{
    const name = row[0];
    const pom = row[4];
    
    const user = {
      AgentName: name,
      DateOfEvaluation: row[2]
    };
    
    emailTemplate.user = user;
    emailTemplate.id = pom;

    pdfTemplate['qe'] = row[0];
    pdfTemplate['de'] = row[1];
    pdfTemplate['eb'] = row[2];
    pdfTemplate['pn'] = pom;
    pdfTemplate['ct'] = row[5];
    pdfTemplate['es'] = row[6];
    pdfTemplate['q1'] = row[7];
    pdfTemplate['q2'] = row[8];
    pdfTemplate['q3'] = row[10];
    pdfTemplate['q4'] = row[11];
    pdfTemplate['q5'] = row[12];
    pdfTemplate['q6'] = row[13];
    pdfTemplate['q7'] = row[14];
    pdfTemplate['q8'] = row[15];
    pdfTemplate['q9'] = row[16];
    pdfTemplate['q10'] = row[17];
    pdfTemplate['q11'] = row[18];
    pdfTemplate['q12'] = row[19];
    pdfTemplate['q13'] = row[20];
    pdfTemplate['q14'] = row[21];
    pdfTemplate['q15'] = row[22];
    pdfTemplate['q16'] = row[23];
    pdfTemplate['cm'] = row[24];

    const htmlBody = emailTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    const pdfBody = pdfTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

    const blob = Utilities.newBlob(pdfBody, MimeType.HTML).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    blob.setName(row[0] + ' ' + row[1] + '.pdf');
    const email = row[3];
    const subject = 'Quality Evaluation PDF ' + row[0] + ' ' + row[4];

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: htmlBody,
      attachments: [blob]
    });
  });
}`
```

Here is the HTML Template

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqWDgdn-ZKI6jxvL-nKw7W6DDTyk?e=tVngMM" alt="Logo" style="width: 200px;">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: right;">
            <h3>Quality Evaluation</h3>
            <p>Quality Evaluation for: {qe}</p>
            <p>Date of Evaluation: {de}</p>
            <p>Evaluation made by: {eb}</p>
            <p>POM Number: {pn}</p>
            <p>Call Type: {ct}</p>
            <p>Evaluation Score: {es}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <hr>
      <h4>Greeting</h4>
      <p>Did the agent use a professional tone of voice when greeting the Caller? {q1}</p>
      <p>Did the agent use proper greeting? {q2}</p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Call Etiquette</h4>
      <p>Did the agent listen actively and patiently to the caller's concerns? {q3}</p>
      <p>Did the agent avoid interrupting the caller during the call? {q4}</p>
      <p>Did the agent speak clearly and enunciate their words? {q5}</p>
      <p>Used courteous/professional language? {q6}</p>
      <p>Did the agent verify the Address, Customer name, POM#? {q7}</p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Process</h4>
      <p>Did the agent call the phone number in POM? {q8}</p>
      <p>Did the agent call 2nd number (if applicable)? {q9}</p>
      <p>Did the agent leave a voicemail? {q10}</p>
      <p>Did the agent email customer and SMS? {q11}</p>
      <p>Did the agent follow Special Instructions? {q12}</p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Email Quality</h4>
      <p>Was the email addressed to the correct recipient(s)? (HUB Manager EAM Team or Dispatch If applicable VP) {q13}</p>
      <p>Was the email clear and concise? {q14}</p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Pinnacle Note Quality</h4>
      <p>Did the agent include any special instructions or notes provided by the customer or Driver in the order documentation? {q15}</p>
      <p>Did the agent follow specific protocols or procedures for documenting orders in the system as outlined in the company's training materials or guidelines? {q16}</p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Comments</h4>
      <p>Comments or Observations {cm}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

you can see in the screenshot is not changing "{qe}" with the result from the google sheet? any advise on how I can have the PDF template update with the results?

I have tried using a google doc as the template, also for the PDF to be created in the code and not use the HTML template.

Comment: Where can I see `screenshot` of `you can see in the screenshot is not changing "{qe}" with the result from the google sheet?`? About `I have tried using a google doc as the template, also for the PDF to be created in the code and not use the HTML template.`, when I saw your showing script, it seems that Google Document is not used. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your question. How about this?

Comment: Please add screenshot.

Comment: @CodeHunter I added 3 screenshots, one of the email that is sent with PDF attached, 2nd of PDF after is sent and last of google sheets.